# Createting observable streams - interaction between Subject and Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Whenever we want to pump some values into an observable stream, we often use a pattern like this:

```
private readonly loadTriggerSubject = new Subject<any>();

private readonly loadTrigger$ = this.loadTriggerSubject.pipe(
  // operators
);

onScroll() {
  this.loadTriggerSubject.next();
}
```

then within the same component we can use the output stream of `$loadTrigger$`, e.g.:

```
private readonly load$ = combineLatest(
  this.limit$,
  this.loadTrigger$,
  (limit, trigger) => ({ limit, trigger }),
).pipe(
  // operators
);
```

`onScroll()` basically trigger the whole machinery, but it feels that there is so much boilerplate. Is there a way to omit explicitly separating the observable from its subject in order to simplify the code above but still have `loadTrigger$` observable emit when `onScroll()` is fired??

Comment: Where are you separating Observable from Subject? Subject implements both Observable and Observer. The whole point of Subject is you can call next and subscribe on the same object.

Comment: (scroll)="loadTriggerSubject.next($event)", put it directly in the template

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the subject in this case, you can create an observable directly from the `scroll` event with `Rx.fromEvent`. I am not familiar with angular components, but essentially this is what you need to do:

```
const scroll$ = Rx.fromEvent(elementBeingScrolled, 'scroll')
const load$ = Rx.combineLatest(scroll$, this.limit$)
```

Also I am hesitant as to why your would need the values emitted from either `scroll$` or `limit$`. `scroll$` is emitting empty values in the example you have above, though I dont know what is coming out of `limit$`. If you do not need those values, you can omit the line `(limit, trigger) => ({ limit, trigger })`, which just controls which values are passed to the rest of the stream.